# How to get the three most common foreign keys from a table in a T-SQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

My DBMS professor wants me to write a SQL procedure which checks whether an entered author ID is one of the three most common authors in a table of problems. Authors which work on the most problems, at least the top three, get higher raises applied to their entries in the `Author` table.

Each entry in the `Problem` table has an `AuthorID` as a foreign key. I need to count the number of problems associated with each author and list them in order so that I can check if the `AuthorID` passed as a parameter into the procedure is one of the top three entries in the counted list.

Finding that list isn't the problem. There are plenty of other problems showing how to use `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and `COUNT()` to find the table of highest authors. The issue is that SQL Server doesn't seem to want me to select the information from a table created by `GROUP BY`.

I can use if-then statements after that to finish off.

The problem table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Problem
(
    pid int,
    pname varchar(255),
    max_score int,
    aid int
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is:

```
select aid
from (select aid,  rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from Problem
      group by aid
     ) a
where seqnum <= 3;
```

This demonstrates combining window functions with aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is not stored procedure, this is just query, but may be this what you need?

```
select aid from (
    select aid,  rank() over(order by cnt desc) rnk from (
        select aid, count(*) cnt
        from Problem
        group by aid
    ) t
) tt
where rnk <= 3;
```